# How does an active filter transfer function translate to a block diagram?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, control-system, transfer-function

I am having troubles trying to translate when finding a transfer function of an active filter is it in a 'Close loop' or 'Open loop' state?

When finding the transfer function of these active op-amps how come we don't include the characteristics of the op amp itself?

For example a Op-Amp has an Op-loop gain I would imagine you need to include that in your transfer function otherwise you could use any op amp/disregard any op amp?

Example: Sallen-Key Butterworth Filter of 2nd Order

$$ H(s) = \frac{1}{C_1 C_2 R_1 R_2 s^2 + C_2 R_1 s + C_2 R_2 s + 1}$$

[image]

Its confusing as the OP-amp has a feedback of 1.

Closed Loop:

[image]

Open Loop:

[image]

Comment: *Its confusing as the OP-amp has a feedback of 1.* There is another feedback path, through C1. Why open loop vs closed loop? The circuit has a transfer function H(s). That the circuit creates that function using internal feedback is irrelevant (for H(s) ). Only if you want to make a block diagram of the circuit including all feedback loops should you also draw these loops.

Comment: The reason why I am planning on discretizing the plant and I have no idea if its an open loop or close loop state. Ah fair it does have another path

Comment: If there is a denominator, and not just some constant, there is feedback. What you refer to as "*feedback of 1*" is wrong to think that the numerator represents the feedback, since the expression is `V(out)/V(in)`, that is, you multiply the denominator of the transfer function with `V(out)`, and the numerator with `V(in)`.

Comment: I dont think the numerator represented the feedback, I just said that due to looking at the op-amp itself. It does have a feedback of 1. The negative terminal has a path to the output

Comment: *and I have no idea if its an open loop or close loop state* Is there a loop through which  a signal can travel back in the direction of the input? Then the loop is closed. Open loop is usually only considered in analysis, the loop is **opened** and then examined **if** the loop would be stable **if** is was closed.

Comment: I see, so the transfer function thats representing that active filter is close loop. What about that capacitor, its being fed forward to the ouput but not exactly at the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am having troubles trying to translate when finding a transfer function of an active filter is it in a 'Close loop' or 'Open loop' state?*

Of course, the filter function is available in a closed-loop condition only. It is the frequency-variable feedback network which gives the desired filter characteristic.

*When finding the transfer function of these active op-amps how come we don't include the characteristics of the op amp itself?*

It is common practice to assume idealized opamps only (infinite gain, no frequency dependent gain). Of course, this simplification causes errors in the transfer characteristic - however, this is acceptable as long as the operating frequency range is limited to a region where other uncertainties (parts tolerances) are dominating. Of course, this means that opamp based filters are used not in the upper MHz range (where opamp non-idealities play a remarkable role).

Please note, that there are many, many different lowpass circuit alternatives which ALL would have the same transfer function in practice (reality) - under the assumption of IDEAL opamps. The difference between these alternatives can be revealed only for REAL opamps. In this context, it is important if the opamp is used as a fixed-gain positive amplifier (Sallen-Key) or as a high-gain amplifier (multi-feedback) or as an integrator (state-variable structures). All these alternatives have different sensitivities against opamp non-idealities.

*For example a Op-Amp has an Op-loop gain I would imagine you need to include that in your transfer function otherwise you could use any op amp/disregard any op amp?*

Of course, theoretically we could include the open-loop gain of the amplifier into the overall transfer function....but for which purpose? To slightly improve the accuracy of the function ? The price for it would be a very complicated transfer function which is very hard to use for practical realisations.

**Remark:** There are studies which show how the frequency-dependent open-loop gain of an opamp can be exploited - together with a pure resistive feedback network without external capacitors - for realizing active filters ("R-filter). However, as a severe drawback, it is necessary to know the exact open-loop gain opamp characteristic, which has very large tolerances. Buth these filters have no practical relevance....

**Comment 1**: Of course, it is possible to create a block diagram in the classical form with a feedback block (and with a summing junction at the input) and a block with the opamps open-loop gain - but for which purpose?

**Comment 2:** Actually, as an advantage of block diagram visualization, it is very easy to see HOW the S&K lowpass works: There is a passive lowpass (Hforward) with a bad quality factor (pole-Q) Qp<0.5.

However, in the "critical" frequency region (exactly at the pole frequency) the bandpass in the feedback path enhances the amplitude of the lowpass because the bandpass has the same pole frequency (zero phase shift, positive feedback effect). This effect produces a larger Q value (Example: Qp=0.7071 for a Butterworth response).

**EDIT:** Block diagram: Both passive transfer functions (lowpass, bandpasss) are derived from the original circuit. Vp is the signal voltage at the positive (non-inverting) opamp input terminal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP0M01.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the read, put a lot of things together. To answer your comment, I was about to say. The reason I asked about this is because I want to discretize the Butter worth filter and I dont know which way to do it either using, Tusin, ZoH, etc. I thought having it in block diagram form would help me decide which method to use. For curiosity sake assuming ideal op amps. Is that block diagram correct if not what would it look like?

Comment: It is not a simple task to create a block diagram....give me some time (until tomorrow).

Comment: Not a problem. Appreciate the help regardless. Any thought on discretizing the Butter worth filter using ZoH or Tustin?

Comment: Please explain: ZoH ...Tustin?

Comment: Zero Order Hold, Tustin method from transforming continuous to discrete. Thank yo so much for the block diagram

Comment: Thank you for this information...by the way (with regard to time discrete operation): Are you familiar with switched-capacitor techniques?

Comment: Not really, but it did come up a couple of times during my research of this. Is it essentially an ADC?

Comment: No - as a rough desription: Resistors are replaced by switched capacitors.....a special form of sampled data systems (time-discrete signal processing). Something between analog and digital filters (time-discrete but amplitude continuous)

Comment: Oh? Would that mean you're implementing discrete in a continuous system? If not I envisioned it more so converting this Butter worth filter into purely digital. I think I may have worded myself wrong but I think I know what you're talking about

Comment: No, it is not as simple....there are some special structures (integrators) that are realized asa ampled data system. You canot convert each analog structure into a switsched-cap topology.

Comment: Oh? I was given the impression you can design a filter in the time domain and then convert it into the discrete domain for the "ease" of it. I am not sure if we are on the same page. I am not trying to convert it to the switch - cap topology but more so into the Z-transform then into a difference equation and implement that into a MCU. I already have the Z transfer function and its displaying the same behavior as the analog filter. I was just curious as which discrete method from converting into the Z -domain was better, as each method have their own ways when to use them

Comment: OK - I see. Yes - your approach should be possible. But your reference filter should be designed first in the frequency domain...I think.

Comment: Sorry when I say time domain I mean frequency. Its already designed and ready to be transformed into the Z domain just need to know the best method to use to transform it. That transfer function I have above is all the specs I want

Comment: Are you trying to use a - more or less - unconventional method for finding a digital structure for a second-order lowpass? (As you certainly know, there are established methods for transferring transfer functions from the s-domain into the z-domain).

Comment: No, not trying to at least. What sparked this whole thing was watching Brain Douglas video. To be exact https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yetLPW9sQaI&t=303s to 11:59. He talks about how if the ZoH was used it takes in account of the DAC and should be careful as if you already have a DAC in the system "Block diagram" it would account for it twice. He also mentioned if you want to transform your continuous model without taking in the DAC into account use the tustin method. This confused me a lot because if you are working in discrete will you always have a DAC so wouldn't you always want to use Zo

Answer (score 2):

> When finding the transfer function of these active op-amps how come we don't include the characteristics of the op amp itself?

Generally you want to operate at frequency/gain underneath the gain bandwidth product. That way the op-amp dynamics don't come into play.

Comment: Michael....are you sure? I have some experience with gyrator applications for active filters. However, I have never seen that somebody exploits the frequency-dependent gain of the opamps for this purpose. I rather think, active inductors and FDNR`s are designed assumng IDEAL opams only..

Comment: @LvW "frequency/gain underneath the gain bandwidth product" he does that exactly to avoid reaching the limit of the amp op.

Comment: jDAQ..you misunderstood something. My comment was to Michael`s claim: "...realizing impedances ..the opamp`s integrator like response is used". That means, he thinks that the real opamp`s frequency-dependent gain would be exploited - and this is not the case.

Comment: @LvW Excuse my mistake, I misremembered. You are correct, I have edited the response to fix this.

Comment: Michael...no problem....misunderstandings cannot be avoided

Answer (score 2):

@LvW Answer is just perfect.

But just for fun, I think you can accomplish your task. From this base schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fImt7Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can model the amplifier as a input impedance and controlled voltage source in series with an output impedance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYL40P.png)</sup>

Of source we can rearrange the circuit to become more easy to visualize its meshes and nodes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUZZ4W.png)</sup>

Now, I have used mesh analysis (tough I tried with node and didn't like were it was going) to obtain the filter transfer function (after many more hours than I thought it would be necessary and many possible mistakes):

\$H(s)= \frac{A_{ol}(s)Z_{i}(s)+Z_o(s)[1+s C_1 (R_2+Z_i(s))]}{A_{ol}Z_i(s)[s^2C_1C_2 R_1 R_2+s C_2(R_1+R_2)+1] +  s^2C_1C_2 \frac{R_1R_2Z_o(s)Z_i(s)}{R_1//R_2//Z_o(s)//Z_i(s)}+ s[ C_2(R_1+R_2)(Z_o(s)+Z_i(s)) + C_1((Z_i(s)+R_1)(Z_o+R_2)] + (R_1+R_2) +Z_o(s) + Z_i(s)}\$

Curiously, but not a proof per se, if you rearrange terms to only have \$1/Z_i\$ and \$1/A\$ format and take the limit of \$Z_0 \rightarrow 0\$, \$Z_i \rightarrow \infty\$ and \$A_{ol} \rightarrow \infty\$ (only the terms with \$Z_i\$ \$A\$ are nonzero) it will become the given original and simpler transfer function.

\$H(s)= \frac{A_{ol}(s)Z_{i}(s)}{s^2C_1C_2 R_1 R_2 A_{ol}Z_i(s)+ s C_2 (R_1+R_2)  Z_i(s)A_{ol}(s) + Z_i(s)A_{ol}(s)} = \frac{1}{s^2C_1C_2 R_1 R_2 + s C_2 (R_1+R_2)  + 1}\$

I think this may be partially useful just to show that there isn't a simple block transfer multiplication, but it will take into account very relevant limitations of the amplifier. Any additional limitation will imply that linear operators and transfer functions can't properly describe it.

Since this took me a lot more hours than I expected I am planning to write another one or a edit to this one with a very different approach exploiting a similar idea that @LvW diagrams leads to, unfortunately yesterday the diagram was not uploaded yet.

Edit 1 : Following @LvW suggestion, we can model the amplifier as \$A_{ol}(s) = G\frac{\omega_0^2}{s^2+2 \xi \omega_0s +\omega_0^2}\$ and \$Z_i(s)=R_i\$ and \$Z_o(s)=R_o\$. Curiously, after doing this and finding some 2 algebraic manipulation errors, its not hard to separate the amplifier gain characteristic indeed, as corrected above. The new transfer function with the second order filter is now:

\$H(s)= \frac{G R_{i}\omega_0^2+(s^2+2\xi\omega_0+\omega_0^2)R_o[1+s C_1 (R_2+R_i)]}{G\omega_0^2R_i[s^2C_1C_2 R_1 R_2+s C_2(R_1+R_2)+1] +  (s^2+2\xi\omega_0+\omega_0^2)[s^2C_1C_2 \frac{R_1R_2R_oR_i}{R_1//R_2//R_o//R_i}+ s[ C_2(R_1+R_2)(R_o+R_i) + C_1(R_i+R_1)(R_o+R_2)] + (R_1+R_2) +Z_o(s) + Z_i(s)]}\$

Which is truly an horrific expression.

Comment: You can assume with good precision that \$Z_i(s) \approx R_i\$ just as \$Z_o(s) \approx R_o\$.

Comment: Trevor..I wonder how the transfer function would look like if you replace Aol(s) with a second-order gain function... ..I think, this would convince the questioner that it makes no sense to incorporate all the non-idealities of the opoamp into the filter function.